# Как передать данные в сам vueX?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Мой `input` связан через `v-model` и хранится в локальной переменной компонента. И мне нужно получить доступ к этой локальной переменной в самом vuex, как это можно сделать?
Повторюсь, не получить данные из vuex в компонент, а наоборот получить из компонента в сам vuex. Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Нужно это для того, чтоб подтянуть данные с инпута, в шаблонную строку ${}.

```
await fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=${}`)
```

Comment: Данные в Vuex передаются действиями и мутациями. Получать из глобального хранилища какие-то локальные значения - не надо, это грубая ошибка с крайне-крайне негативными эффектами. Все что должно использоваться в действиях, заноси в стор через мутации... это единственно верный путь в Vuex.

Comment: Ну а если данные используются не действиями, а только одним действием - передавай эти данные пэйлоадом (вполне очевидно вроде, но на всякий случай напишу).

Comment: @yar85 мне нужно не получать из стора в компонент, а наоборот из компонента получить доступ в самом сторе, чтоб я смог подставить это значение tsyms=${сюда}`)

Comment: Значит, тебе нужно вовсе прекратить использовать Vue и Vuex, из-за противоречия нужд идеологии этих библиотек. Но заменить их будет нечем - т.к. то что тебе нужно, вроде как _везде_ считается антипаттерном.

Comment: @yar85 почему? Все данные в основном выношу в общий стор, но мой инпут связан с локальной переменной, разве ее никак не могу подставить в vuex?

Comment: _«почему?»_ - Что именно "почему"? _«разве ее никак не могу подставить в vuex?»_ - думаю что не можешь, т.к. здесь спрашиваешь как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Сделай computed свойство и прокинь его в инпут.
В экшене прописывай данные в стор и fetch дергай.

```
value: {
   get() {
       return this.$store.state.value
   },
   set(value) {
       this.$store.dispath('valueActions', value)
   }
}
```